# How to reassemble all wireshark packets at once to original file sent?

Tags: email, wireshark

I know that if I use the Follow UDP Stream option I'll be able to reassemble one captured e-mail in WireShark.

I captured like 100 000 e-mail packages in order to test my anti spam filter and now I need to reassemble them all. It's not possible to do that clicking one by one.

Is there any way I can do that in WireShark? Reassemble a lot of packages at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure how to do it in Wireshark, but you CAN do it using [Netwitness](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-netwitness.htm):

[image]

Your best bet would be to filter all mail from the PCAP file in Wireshark with a filter: say **SMTP**, apply the filter, go to file/save as, then choose **selected packet**, save that file. Open that file in Netwitness and see the image above. It will throw everything into an appropriate folder.